# Custom event error while testing with Codeception in Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, codeception, active-form

Im having the same error every time I run Codeception acceptance tests more than once in Yii2.

Below is the error stack :

> [UnknownServerException] Error Message => 'URL '`http://localhost/project/backend/web/index.php/user/list`' didn't load. Error: 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CustomEvent''
>    caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Content-Length":"85","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:4444"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"url\":\"http:\/\/localhost\/project\/backend\/web\/index.php\/user\/list\"}","url":"/url","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"url","directory":"/","path":"/url","relative":"/url","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/url","queryKey":{},"chunks":["url"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/3f1a3090-e4fc-11e4-acf5-cdfb0adce833/url"}

And thats the Cest class code (I dont think that the problem will be into the code):

```
use \AcceptanceTester;
use \Yii;

class CreateUserCest
{

// private $username;
// private $email;

## I don't think this work, but neither is the problem (if I commented it the error persists)
public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    try{
        $this->login($I, 'admin@admin.com', 'foobar');        
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $I->amGoingTo('Jump login cuz Im already logged');
    }
}

public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
}

private function login(AcceptanceTester $I, $email, $password)
{
    $I->amOnPage('/backend/web/index.php/site/login');
    $I->amGoingTo('Log in the application');
    $I->see("Login");
    $I->fillField("#loginform-email", $email);
    $I->fillField("#loginform-password", $password);
    $I->click('Login');
    $I->see(Yii::t('app', 'Go to').' backoffice'); // We are succesfull logued
}

// Just username, email and password
public function createEmptyOne(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $username = "UsuarioTest".rand(1, 10000);
    $email = "UsuarioTest".rand(1, 10000)."@test.com";

    $I->amGoingTo("Create a user with the basic data (username, email, password)");
    $I->amOnPage("/backend/web/index.php/user/create"); ## 16/04/2015 Page loading never ends because of JS error
    $I->fillField("#signupform-username", $username);
    $I->fillField("#signupform-email", $email);
    $I->fillField("#signupform-password", 'attime7931');
    // $I->click(Yii::t('app', 'Confirm'));
    $I->click('Confirmar');
    $I->seeInDatabase('user', ['username' => $username, 'email' => $email]);
}

// List users
public function listUsers(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $username = "UsuarioTest".rand(1, 10000);
    $email = "UsuarioTest".rand(1, 10000)."@test.com";

    $I->amGoingTo("List users");
    $I->haveInDatabase('user', array('username' => $username, 'email' => $email));
    $I->amOnPage("/backend/web/index.php/user/list");
    $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/user/list');
    $I->see('Crear usuario');
    // $I->see(Yii::t('app', 'Create User'));
    // $I->see($username);
    $I->see($email);
}

public function updateUser(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $username = "UsuarioTest".rand(1, 10000);
    $email = "UsuarioTest".rand(1, 10000)."@test.com";
    $I->haveInDatabase('user', array('username' => $username, 'email' => $email));
    $id = $I->grabFromDatabase('user', 'id', ['username' => $username, 'email' => $email]);

    $I->amGoingTo("Update user with id $id");
    $I->amOnPage("/backend/web/index.php/user/update/$id");
    $I->see('Datos principales');
    $I->see($username);
    $I->see($email);
}

}
```

I'm getting this error at the Chrome console (I have tried to run the tests in Firefox also, and it returns me the same result):

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

When I click at the error it points at this line

> jQuery('#w0').yiiGridView({"filterUrl":"/project/backend/web/index.php/user/list","filterSelector":"#w0-filters input, #w0-filters select"});

**EDIT**

I have tried to fix the yiiGridView error by adding jQuery-2.1.3.min.js to my AppAsset to avoid reloading after the yiiGridView script. And the error persists

**SECOND EDIT**
I have fixed the yiiGridView error and the Custom Event error persists. The reason have to be another

Comment: What module are you using to execute the acceptance tests? PhPBrowser, Selenium, WebDriver, etc?